# To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files - Ubuntu

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

error in install package baibaratsky/php-webmoney in Ubuntu server 14.0.4 in ssh with this code:

```
composer require baibaratsky/php-webmoney

root@euv:/var/www/my# composer require baibaratsky/php-webmoney
Key kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 25
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^0.15.1 for baibaratsky/php-webmoney
./composer.json has been updated
Key kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 25
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - linslin/yii2-curl 1.0.8 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - linslin/yii2-curl 1.0.8 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - linslin/yii2-curl 1.0.8 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for linslin/yii2-curl (locked at 1.0.8, required as *) -> satisfiable by linslin/yii2-curl[1.0.8].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

i installed this package but dont fix error.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

Comment: This output clearly states that you need `curl` so install `php5-curl`

Comment: `requires ext-curl` should be a hint...

Comment: thankyou with install CURL fix this error

Answer (score 1):

install CURL fix this error

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

You will need to restart the server afterwards:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively, if you are using php-fpm, you'll need to restart php5-fpm instead

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```